# Adding HtmlAgilityPack to android project in visual studio 2013

Tags: android, visual-studio-2013, html-agility-pack

I have a solution in Visual studio 2013 where I have a Windows store project. I have installed `HtmlAgilityPack` from  the NuGet and referenced it to this project and everything works.

Now I have added a Android project and want to reference the same `HtmlAgilityPack` to it as well. But I get the following error while I try to install the Pack again.

```
HtmlAgilityPack 1.4.6' already installed.
Adding 'HtmlAgilityPack 1.4.6' to MyProject.Droid.
Could not install package 'HtmlAgilityPack 1.4.6'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v4.0.3', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
```

Also, If I try to change the Android Target to `v4.0.3` , The error still remains.

Any suggestion is appreciated.
Thanks